# Inject NodePort value based on how many jobs are running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a lot of jobs in kubernetes that have to be exposed, so each ConfigMap has a NodePort. Instead of hardcoding a NodePort to each job I decided to look if Helm charts may help the code be more flexible.

The question: Is it possible to assign a NodePort to a job, depending on how many of them are deployed before?
E.g: first job runs with ports 32001, 32002, I apply the second one and ports 32003, 32004 get assigned to it.

Comment: If the port number isn't going to be known anyways, you can omit the `nodePort: 31245` setting and let Kubernetes choose a port for you.  I've seen some charts include a relevant `kubectl get service -o jsonpath=...` command in their Helm `NOTES.txt` file.

Comment: is there any way to specify the range of the ports that kubernetes can choose from? I would like it to choose from 32000 to for example 32050

Comment: That's cluster-level configuration and not something you can specify as an application developer.

Comment: thank you very much, I will note that